# VBA: need to default control value if only 1 possible result or show list if more than possible result

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to write a bit of code, in VBA, that would restrict the possible values in a select list if certain criteria are met or, if only one possible value, default the value in the control to that one possible value or return a null list if no possible values.

To be more specific, in a form, I have an EventDate and ProtocolID. The protocols have a `BeginImplementationDate` and `EndImplmentationDate`. If the EventDate falls between the `BeginImplementationDate` and `EndImplementationDate` (which can be null, if the protocol is still active) of more than 1 protocol, I need to show all the ProtocolIDs for those protocols in the drop-down list. If only 1 protocol meets that criteria, the field needs to default to the ProtocolID that qualifies. If zero protocols meet the criteria, the drop-down list will be empty.

Comment: so you need to set the record source of your combo box to a query resutl? What a damn shame this isnt so easily available :P <3

Comment: @DougCoats You must really be bored.

Comment: @nicomp I like being helpful while simultanouesly being somewhat sadistic for those who need to learn how to google better

Comment: In my defense i did serve up the answer (kind of) on a silver platter

Comment: @DougCoats The poor guy has a deadline for a client. The least we can do is write his query for him so he can have some billable hours.

Comment: @DougCoats I did set the combo box to a query result but that only delivered the list of protocols within the parameters. It doesn't assign the result, if only 1, as the default (not a list containing 1 item). So it seems like I have to do a count(?) to find out if I have Case1: more than 1 result, or Case2: count of 1, or Case3: count of 0. And then return the results in a list for case1, default the control for case2, and probably a message (warning) for case3. And, yes, maybe I don't know how to properly "Google" that question, though I've tried several ways.

Comment: @scubydu671 I think you should probably leanr how to combine IIF and DCOUNT to delehgate what kind of result you get.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the *DefaultValue* of the combobox with a small subfunction which you, for example, could call when opening the form:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Call SetDefaultProtocol

End Sub


Private Sub SetDefaultProtocol()

    Dim DefaultValue    As String

    With Me!ComboProtocol
        If .ListCount = 1 + Abs(.ColumnHeads) Then
            DefaultValue = .ItemData(Abs(.ColumnHeads))
        End If
        .DefaultValue = DefaultValue
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is what I did to resolve the problem.

```
Private Sub txtEventDate_AfterUpdate()
    Dim intProtocolCount As Integer
    Dim intProtocolID As Integer

    intProtocolCount = DCount("ID", "lu_Protocol", "BeginImplementationDate<=#" & Me.EventDate & "# and Nz([EndImplementationDate],Date())>=#" & Me.EventDate & "#")

    If intProtocolCount = 1 Then
        intProtocolID = DLookup("ID", "lu_Protocol", "BeginImplementationDate<=#" & Me.EventDate & "# and Nz([EndImplementationDate],Date())>=#" & Me.EventDate & "#")
        Me.cmbProtocol = intProtocolID
        Me.cmbProtocol.Requery
    ElseIf intProtocolCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("No Protocol is active for this Event Date. If Event Date is correct, please contact the Data Manager to update the Protocol list in the database.")
        Me.cmbProtocol.Requery
    Else
        Me.cmbProtocol.Requery
    End If
End Sub
```